# creating an oracle function

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

The following code creates an object table with a `get_age` function using oracle sql*plus.

```
Create Type C_type as Object(
  Cname varchar(30),
  dob  Date,
  classification Number,
  sample_clip Blob
)
/

ALTER TYPE C_type
  ADD MEMBER FUNCTION get_age RETURN INTEGER;


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY C_type AS
MEMBER FUNCTION get_age RETURN INTEGER IS
currenttime_age integer; 
BEGIN
  currenttime_age := (SYSDATE - dob)/365.25; 
  RETURN currenttime_age;   
END get_age;
END;
/
```

my intention is to add another function that returns a character

- classification  as 'short' (if below 5), 'medium' ( between 5-45 ) and 'long' (over 45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.  My Bad.

```
DROP TYPE c_type
/

CREATE TYPE C_type AS OBJECT
(
   Cname VARCHAR (30),
   dob DATE,
   classification NUMBER,
   sample_clip BLOB,
   MEMBER FUNCTION get_age
      RETURN INTEGER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION get_class
      RETURN VARCHAR2
)
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY C_type
AS
   MEMBER FUNCTION get_age
      RETURN INTEGER
   IS
      currenttime_age   INTEGER;
   BEGIN
      currenttime_age := (SYSDATE - dob) / 365.25;
      RETURN currenttime_age;
   END get_age;


   MEMBER FUNCTION get_class
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      result   VARCHAR2 (10);
   BEGIN
      result :=
         CASE
            WHEN classification < 5 THEN 'short'
            WHEN classification BETWEEN 5 AND 45 THEN 'medium'
            WHEN classification > 45 THEN 'long'
         END;

      RETURN result;
   END get_class;
END;
/
```

Comment: @ LeorA, i get this error Warning: Type Body created with compilation errors.

Comment: See my update.  Made some corrections.

Comment: Oops my bad.  Had run on test database, and did not reomve schema.  Thanks for catching that!